# Get one "cell" from a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a site which settings are stored in a mysql database table.
For getting one setting, I use something like this:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT setting FROM settings WHERE id=1");
$a = mysql_fetch_array($q);
$setting = $a['setting'];
```

But, isn't there a faster/better way to dump just one "cell" of a mysql table in a variable?

Comment: All `mysql_*` functions are [**officially deprecated**](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp) *(no longer supported/maintained)* and will be [**removed**](http://j.mp/11j2t6j) in the future. You should update your code using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure future functionality.

Comment: You can write a method to do this for you

Comment: Just did some research on mysqli. I didn't do anything with PHP for years so I wasn't aware that mysql is obsolute and mysqli is the new way to go. In the internet I see that mysqli supports procedural programmming as well. Since I already started my project in mysql and don't to change to object oriented programming, is it save to say that I can replace all mysql() commands to mysqli() commands by just adding the "i"? So in the example above, will mysqli_query() and mysqli_fetch_array() work the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's pretty much it. Some DB libraries offer a `->getOne()`-type method, but internally they don't anything different than what you are. Of course, you SHOULD stop using mysql_*() functions. They're deprecated/obsolete. Consider switching to mysqli or PDO

Comment: Just did some research on mysqli. I didn't do anything with PHP for years so I wasn't aware that mysql is obsolute and mysqli is the new way to go. In the internet I see that mysqli supports procedural programmming as well. Since I already started my project in mysql and don't to change to object oriented programming, is it save to say that I can replace all mysql() commands to mysqli() commands by just adding the "i"? So in the example above, will mysqli_query() and mysqli_fetch_array() work the same?

Comment: for the most part, yeah, you just add the `i`.